# Do any, all, or no adjustments to standard model change the Weinberg angle or it’s relation to masses or coupling constants?

Tags: standard-model, symmetry-breaking, higgs, electroweak, beyond-the-standard-model

Do any, all, or no adjustments to standard model change the Weinberg angle or it’s relation to masses or coupling constants?
If any, which (types of) ones?
For the ones that do, what are the relations between the (types of) adjustments and the changes?

Comment: It's defined by
$$ \cos\theta =  \frac{m_W}{m_Z}$$

Comment: Sorry.  That did not answer any of my questions. I would like to know how it changes with changes to the structure of the standard model.